# Handling constants when summing total complexity of a program

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I wrote a program which performs a BFS (Breadth First Search) on a graph.
The program's execution is divided into an initialization phase and the algorithm phase. 
Given that V is the number of vertices and E is the number of edges:
I've calculated the complexity for the initialization to be O(V+2E) and the for algorithm to be O(V+E). 
What is the complexity of the entire program in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be `O(V+E)`. Constants are ignored in big-O notation:

```
O(cf(x)) = O(f(x))
c*O(f(x)) = O(f(x))
```

Of course, `c` should be a constant.